# Style EditText underline color android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml, android-background

I am creating a application that has couple of edittext's that chang color when the edittext has focus or not. When the view has the focus the color should be blue, when normal it should have white color, something like this:

[image]

I've tried creating two nine patches and setting the background according to this xml but seems its not working. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this ?

Xml selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_blue" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_white" />
</selector>
```

Thanks

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262935/android-edittext-bottom-line-color-and-theme-changes/35263829#35263829 hope it will help you.

Comment: What resources do you have? Can you show spelling_blue and spelling_white?

Comment: Try to
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_blue"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_white"/>
</selector>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `android:state_window_focused`.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_blue" /> <!-- pressed -->    
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_blue" /> <!-- focused -->    
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/spelling_white" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```